# Compare/Fetch 2 json files having same key but in different order in java?

Tags: java, json

Need to fetch the values of the "keys" in json1 file from json2 file maintaining the hierarchy.
(Dynamically) .The two files may vary.

json file 1
{
   "id":"",
   "logic":[ {
      "message":"",
      "represent":{
         "name":"",
         "date":""
      }
  } ]
}

json file2
{
"compare":"newjson",
 "id":"123",
   "logic":[
      {
         "message":"hello",
         "represent":{
            "name":"Labs"
            "date":"23-09-19"
         },
         "represent-or":{
            "name":"New+code",

```
     }]
```

}

Comment: Where is your code that is trying to achieve that?

Comment: i just want to know the logic that can be used..
not the code..

Comment: i have parsed and got each element of the the two json ..but now what to know thw logic of comparing the elements maintaining the hierarchy.